# Memory limits in excel

Tags: memory, microsoft-excel-2010

What is the memory limit in an excel session (32 bit excel 2010 operating under windows 7)?

I have read conflicting reports: some say that there is 2gb available to excel, and others say that there is 2gb to be dsitributed between all the Microsoft applications.

I ask as when I open excel 2010 (32 bit) with a few (large) plugins that I need to use, I get a System resource exceeded error box when I attempt to update a (fairly small) pivot table.

In either case, are there any work-arounds (other than moving to 64 bit, which is beyond my control) to use the available ram?

I have 12bg on my machine and i can see that there is 7gb unused - at least in theory.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/3066990/memory-usage-in-the-32-bit-edition-of-excel-2013-and-2016) Microsoft page:

> The limit of virtual address space for 32-bit editions of Windows-based applications is 2 gigabytes (GB). For Excel, this space
>   is shared by the Excel application itself together with any add-ins
>   that run in the same process. The size of the worksheet itself also
>   affects the usage of virtual address space. Because Excel loads the
>   worksheet into addressable memory, some worksheets that have a file
>   size of less than 2 GB may still require Excel to use more than 2 GB
>   of addressable memory.

The 2GB memory is shared between Excel and its plug-ins.

The only solution to the no memory error is to stop using such plug-ins or install the 64 bits version of Excel.

Comment: This is correct. It's 2017 and Excel's memory space limits isn't affected by other applications.  You can say this about pretty much any application.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try..

- Can you retry without plugins? Sometimes plugins consume much memory and they share the memory limit with Excel itself. Turn everything off first to check if it actually loads the document successfully and then incrementally turn on some. Go to File - Options - Add-ins - Click "go" with 'Excel Add-ins', 'COM Add-ins' and so on to control add-ins. You may just disable them rather than removing. Something completely unnecessary for you might have caused the problem.
- If you keep multiple documents open at a time, [open multiple excel instances](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/i-want-to-open-2-excel-files-in-separate-windows/f7588d9a-3c41-466f-8f01-3b6ab9661ae3) rather than keep just one process to access everything. (This is default on Excel 2013.)
- (Very experimental and not verified to be safe to apply on Excel) On x64 Windows, it is possible to make [32bit processes access up to 3GB](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=889654) with [EDITBIN utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xd3shwhf.aspx) (available on Visual Studio), by entering the following command on Visual Studio Command Prompt. (Please backup the original Excel.exe before doing this) However, if the problem is not based on the process memory, this won't make any difference as this is only for process memory. See task manager and if the process memory is not more than 1GB when you get the error, don't try this.

> Editbin "C:.....\EXCEL.EXE" /largeaddressaware

If none of them helps, a screenshot might help people here to analyse the problem.